# При выполнении внешней команды shell зависает окно приложения

Tags: python, cmd, shell

Написал программку с таблицей пользователей и ПК(на которых они залогинены, ну и в планах еще выводить некоторую информацию). И для удобства хотел запускать Dameware Mini Remote Control, непосредственно с этого приложения двойным кликом по выбранной строчке, с помощью выполнения внешней команды. Вроде бы все получилось, вот только... После запуска Dameware, мое приложение виснет, отвисает только, когда закрываешь Dameware. Хотелось бы, чтоб приложение оставалось активным, для доступа к информации или запуску второго(и последующих) сессий Dameware(так делать можно).

```
    def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
        item = self.tree.selection()[0]
        subprocess.run(["C:\Program Files (x86)\SolarWinds\Dameware Remote Support\DWRCC.exe", "-c:", "-h:", "-m:{0}".format(self.tree.item(item, 'values')[2])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил созданием потока thread и запуск вызываемого объекта в отдельном потоке.